# Convert binary to hexadecimal using PHP

Tags: php, binary, hex

How do I convert a binary number (i.e. `1111111`) to hexadecimal (i.e. `7f`) using PHP? I recognize I could do `dechex(bindec('1111111'));`, however, I am certain that this is not the right way.

I tried `bin2hex('1111111')` but it resulted in 31313131313131.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your solution is fine. You can also use [base_convert](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base-convert.php).

```
$binary = '1111111';
echo base_convert($binary, 2, 16); // 7f
```

But keep in mind that php is not built for calculations. It is built for working with strings.

Comment: Thanks Sergey.  This seems a little better (or at least more readable).

Answer (score 1):

```
dechex(bindec($binary));
```

It is the right way, you are putting extra ")"(Closing Parenthesis) in the end...

Reference: http://php.net/manual/en/function.bin2hex.php

Comment: Why reference `bin2hex()`?  From the name, one would think it would work, however, not the case.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<?php
$binary = "11111001";
$hex = dechex(bindec($binary));
echo $hex;
?>
```

look at this link for more info
http://php.net/manual/en/function.bin2hex.php

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Comment: You can edit your answer by pressing "edit" on the bottom left. Go ahead, try it out :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this function:

```
<?php

function hexentities($str) {
$return = '';
for($i = 0; $i < strlen($str); $i++) {
    $return .= '&#x'.bin2hex(substr($str, $i, 1)).';';
}
return $return;
 }

?>
```