# How to convert binary to string with PHP

Tags: php

I want to convert a binary string to hexademical with PHP.  The binary string encodes text.

I tried this code:

```
echo pack('H*', base_convert('0100100001100101011011000110110001101111001000000101011101101111011100100110110001100100', 2, 16));
```

But it is not working on long binary strings.

Example: I want 'Hello World', but it is writing 'Hello X'.

How to convert binary to hexadecimal with PHP?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert binary to hexadecimal using PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33985039/convert-binary-to-hexadecimal-using-php)

Answer (score 0):

As said in the php [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.base-convert.php), this is caused because:

> base_convert() may lose precision on large numbers due to properties related to the internal "double" or "float" type used. Please see the Floating point numbers section in the manual for more specific information and limitations.

In the same documentation, there are a few code examples on how to solve this issue, like this one:

```
<?php 
convBase('123', '0123456789', '01234567'); 
//Convert '123' from decimal (base10) to octal (base8).
//result: 173

convBase('70B1D707EAC2EDF4C6389F440C7294B51FFF57BB', '0123456789ABCDEF', '01');
//Convert '70B1D707EAC2EDF4C6389F440C7294B51FFF57BB' from hexadecimal (base16) to binary (base2).
//result: 
//111000010110001110101110000011111101010110000101110
//110111110100110001100011100010011111010001000000110
//001110010100101001011010100011111111111110101011110
//111011

convBase('1324523453243154324542341524315432113200203012', '012345', '0123456789ABCDEF');
//Convert '1324523453243154324542341524315432113200203012' from senary (base6) to hexadecimal (base16).
//result: 1F9881BAD10454A8C23A838EF00F50

convBase('355927353784509896715106760','0123456789','Christopher');
//Convert '355927353784509896715106760' from decimal (base10) to undecimal (base11) using "Christopher" as the numbers.
//result: iihtspiphoeCrCeshhorsrrtrh

convBase('1C238Ab97132aAC84B72','0123456789aAbBcCdD', '~!@#$%^&*()');
//Convert'1C238Ab97132aAC84B72' from octodecimal (base18) using '0123456789aAbBcCdD' as the numbers to undecimal (base11) using '~!@#$%^&*()' as the numbers.
//result: !%~!!*&!~^!!&(&!~^@#@@@&

function convBase($numberInput, $fromBaseInput, $toBaseInput)
{
    if ($fromBaseInput==$toBaseInput) return $numberInput;
    $fromBase = str_split($fromBaseInput,1);
    $toBase = str_split($toBaseInput,1);
    $number = str_split($numberInput,1);
    $fromLen=strlen($fromBaseInput);
    $toLen=strlen($toBaseInput);
    $numberLen=strlen($numberInput);
    $retval='';
    if ($toBaseInput == '0123456789')
    {
        $retval=0;
        for ($i = 1;$i <= $numberLen; $i++)
            $retval = bcadd($retval, bcmul(array_search($number[$i-1], $fromBase),bcpow($fromLen,$numberLen-$i)));
        return $retval;
    }
    if ($fromBaseInput != '0123456789')
        $base10=convBase($numberInput, $fromBaseInput, '0123456789');
    else
        $base10 = $numberInput;
    if ($base10<strlen($toBaseInput))
        return $toBase[$base10];
    while($base10 != '0')
    {
        $retval = $toBase[bcmod($base10,$toLen)].$retval;
        $base10 = bcdiv($base10,$toLen,0);
    }
    return $retval;
}
?>
```

then you can just echo the return value of this function with the [pack()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php) function.