# 64 Binary String to 16 character hex in PHP

Tags: c#, php

I have a 64 character long string, like the following: `0100101000000011111010000101010000111101000011010100010000100110`
That I need to end up in what I believe is a hexidecimal string that is 18 characters long:
`084a0002d43d0d4426`.

The code that currently does this in C# looks like this:

```
private string BinaryStringToHexString(string binary)
{
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder(binary.Length / 8 + 1);

    for (int i = 0; i < binary.Length; i += 8)
    {
        string eightBits = binary.Substring(i, 8);
        result.AppendFormat("{0:X2}", Convert.ToByte(eightBits, 2));
    }

    return result.ToString();
}
```

I'm trying to figure out how this is achieved in PHP, but when using the `dechex` or `binhex` functions in php the format does not end up similar.
Here is my current attempt in PHP:

```
$fullStringToEncode = '0100101000000011111010000101010000111101000011010100010000100110';

for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($fullStringToEncode); $i = $i + 8) {
    $eightBits = substr($fullStringToEncode, $i, 8);
    $result .= sprintf("%02X", dechex($eightBits));
}
```

The above php code gives me `020282220222124a2` which is 17 characters long.

This was based on a few days of googling and trying to figure it out.  Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Methods in C? A binary string that contains stuff that is not '1' or '0'? 16-bit strings that are actually 72 bits long? I'm confused.

Comment: I'm probably using wrong terminology, I guess I was calling it that based on what the C Method name was called `BinaryStringToHexString`

Comment: what is a 64bit string? d

Comment: Yeah, probably, but it's hard to understand what you're asking if you don't use the correct terminology, or at least one that can be translated to something meaningful.

Comment: Anyway that looks an awful lot like C#, now that I look at it. Do you mind if I re-tag your question?

Comment: Updated question, this goes to show what knowledge I have in this area.  I have a 64 character string that I need to end up in an 18 character hex string

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca please, go ahead

Comment: 64 bits equal 8 bytes, two hex represent a byte (00 to FF = 0 to 255), thus you should not end up with more than 16 hex values in any case?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert binary to hexadecimal using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33985039/convert-binary-to-hexadecimal-using-php)

Comment: @krom yea that’s what I was expecting but in the c code he converts the 8 character binary to one byte, in my pho code I can’t do that so the 8 character binary string is more than 1 byte which is why it’s longer than expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input string you currently have `0100101000000011111010000101010000111101000011010100010000100110` will be converted to `4A03E8543D0D4426`, you can confirm this with the `C#` snippet you have or do the conversion by hand. In order to produce `084a0002d43d0d4426` your input should be `000010000100101000000000000000101101010000111101000011010100010000100110`.

That being said, [`dechex(int $number)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dechex.php)  returns a `string` containing the `hex` representation of `$number`. Instead of `dechex`, you can use [`bindec( string $binary_string)`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.bindec.php) which will return the decimal equivalent of the binary number represented by the `$binary_string` argument. Modify your code to use `bindec`:

```
<?php
    $fullStringToEncode = '000010000100101000000000000000101101010000111101000011010100010000100110';

    $result = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($fullStringToEncode); $i = $i + 8) {
        $eightBits = substr($fullStringToEncode, $i, 8);
        $result .= sprintf('%02X', bindec($eightBits));
    }
    echo $result;
?>
```

Outputs:

```
084A0002D43D0D4426
```

Comment: Thanks, will try this and report back.  I appreciate your time.

Comment: This is perfect, thank you.  The output is precisely what I was looking for!

Comment: @MatthewBrown You bet! Glad I could help.